# Remove a specific selector from observer

Tags: iphone, ios, observer-pattern, nsnotificationcenter

Hi I have a problem with notificationCenter. I'm launching the load of three different feeds and I'm registering three notifications with three different selector (the observer object is the same for the three notifications).

notification1 -> selector1

notification2 -> selector2

notification3 -> selector3

All works fine but I can't unregister the observer when I receive the feed content because in that case i'm blocking to receive the other two feeds. otherwise if I don't unregister the observer I'm getting the notification twice if I resend the same query with the same selector and notification name.

Are there any way to unregister just the selector without unregister the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)removeObserver:(id)notificationObserver name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
```

is the method you're looking for. Just pass the correct notificationName for each case.